# Python combine to bytes objects

Tags: python, byte

I want to mix 2 songs.

Here is the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'play_2_mp3_files.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtTest import QSignalSpy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio
import signal
import io
import numpy as np

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 158)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.decode_files(Form))

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Play 2 mp3 files"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Play 2 mp3 files in the same time"))
        
    def decode_files(self,Form):
        self.file_1_decoded = False
        self.decode_file_1()
        self.file_2_decoded = False
        self.decode_file_2()
        
    def decode_file_1(self):
        self.desiredFormat = QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat()
        self.desiredFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(44100)
        self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(1)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)
        self.desiredFormat.setByteOrder(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.SignedInt)
        
        self.m_buffer_1 = QByteArray()
        
        self.decoder_1 = QAudioDecoder()
        self.decoder_1.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer_1)
        self.decoder_1.finished.connect(self.decode_of_file_1_finished)
        self.decoder_1.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
        self.decoder_1.setSourceFilename(r"ΑΓΙΑ ΚΥΡΙΑΚΗ.mp3")   
        self.decoder_1.start()
        
    def decode_of_file_1_finished(self):
        self.file_1_decoded = True
        if(self.file_2_decoded):
            self.play_mp3_files()
        
    def readBuffer_1(self):
        buffer = self.decoder_1.read()
        count = buffer.byteCount()
        if(count>0):
            buffer_data = buffer.constData().asstring(count)
            self.m_buffer_1.append(buffer_data)
        else:
            return 1
            
    def decode_of_file_2_finished(self):
        self.file_2_decoded = True
        if(self.file_1_decoded):
            self.play_mp3_files()
            
    def decode_file_2(self):
        self.m_buffer_2 = QByteArray()
        
        self.decoder_2 = QAudioDecoder()
        self.decoder_2.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer_2)
        self.decoder_2.finished.connect(self.decode_of_file_2_finished)
        self.decoder_2.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
        self.decoder_2.setSourceFilename(r"ΑΓΙΟΣ ΑΝΔΡΕΑΣ.mp3")  
        self.decoder_2.start()
        
    def readBuffer_2(self):
        buffer = self.decoder_2.read()
        count = buffer.byteCount()
        if(count>0):
            buffer_data = buffer.constData().asstring(count)
            self.m_buffer_2.append(buffer_data)
        else:
            return 1
            
    def play_mp3_files(self):
        print("Two files decoded.Lets sound it.")
        self.m_play_called = False
        self.m_time_to_buffer = 50
        self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME = 100
        
        output_devices_qt = QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QtMultimedia.QAudio.AudioOutput)
        
        if (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 44100):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 10) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        elif (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 24000):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 6) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        else:
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 4) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
            
        self.m_audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(output_devices_qt[0], self.desiredFormat)
        self.m_audio_output.setBufferSize(self.internal_buffer_size)
        
        self.m_size_to_buffer = int(self.timeToSize_1())
        
        self.m_max_size_to_buffer = self.m_size_to_buffer + int(self.timeToSize_2())
        
        self.m_output_device = self.m_audio_output.start()
        
        self.timer_play = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
        self.timer_play.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer_play.timeout.connect(lambda:self.preplay(Form))
        self.timer_play.start(10)
        
    def timeToSize_1(self):
        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.m_time_to_buffer / 1000)
    
    def timeToSize_2(self):
        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME / 1000)
    
            
    def preplay(self,Form):
        if(self.m_play_called==False):
            self.m_play_called = True
            self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
            self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
            self.timer.singleShot(0,lambda:self.sound_mp3_files(Form))
            
    def sound_mp3_files(self,Form):
        self.m_play_called = False
        if self.m_buffer_1.isEmpty() and self.m_buffer_2.isEmpty():
            self.stop_playing(Form)
            return
            
        readlen = int(self.m_audio_output.periodSize())
        chunks = int(self.m_audio_output.bytesFree() / readlen)
        
        
        while (chunks>0):
            samples_1 = self.m_buffer_1.mid(0, readlen)
            len_1 = samples_1.size()
            self.m_buffer_1.remove(0, len_1)
            
            samples_2 = self.m_buffer_2.mid(0, readlen)
            len_2 = samples_2.size()
            self.m_buffer_2.remove(0, len_2)
            
            if(self.m_audio_output.state()!=2): 
                if (len_1>0 and len_2>0):
                
                    samples_1_data = list(samples_1.data())
                    samples_2_data = list(samples_2.data())
                    
                    print(np.array(samples_1_data).tobytes())
                    print(samples_1)
                    print("==================")
                    
                    if(len_1>len_2):
                        samples = np.array([((samples_1_data[i]+samples_2_data[i])/2) for i in range(0,len_2)])
                        samples = np.append(samples,np.array([samples_1_data[i]/2 for i in range(len_2,len_1)]))
                    else:
                        samples = np.array([((samples_1_data[i]+samples_2_data[i])/2) for i in range(0,len_1)])
                        samples = np.append(samples,np.array([samples_2_data[i]/2 for i in range(len_1,len_2)]))                    
                    
                    
                    samples = samples.tobytes()
                    
                    samples_final = QByteArray()
                    samples_final.insert(0, samples)
                    
                    self.m_output_device.write(samples_final)
                elif (len_1>0 and len_2==0):
                    print("File 2 finished.")
                    self.m_output_device.write(samples_1)
                elif (len_1==0 and len_2>0):
                    print("File 1 finished.")
                    self.m_output_device.write(samples_2)
            else:
                return 1

            if (len_1 != readlen and len_2 != readlen):
                break

            chunks = chunks - 1
            
    def stop_playing(self,Form):
        self.m_audio_output.stop()
        Form.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt/plugins")
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just trying to mix two songs. The question is how can i do it?
With the above code i hear a slow noise. The convertation is not true.

But when one song stops, i can hear the other song.

Comment: What types are your `buffer_x` objects? Are they equal lengths... and if not - what should happen?

Comment: In general there are not equal. So fill after with the rest of the biger.

Comment: `byteCount()`???

Comment: There are QAudioBuffer()

Comment: @JonClements Question eddited.

Comment: @JonClements Question eddited again.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'play_2_mp3_files.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtTest import QSignalSpy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio
import signal
import io
import numpy as np

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 158)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.decode_files(Form))

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Play 2 mp3 files"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Play 2 mp3 files in the same time"))
        
    def decode_files(self,Form):
        self.file_1_decoded = False
        self.decode_file_1()
        self.file_2_decoded = False
        self.decode_file_2()
        
    def decode_file_1(self):
        self.desiredFormat = QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat()
        self.desiredFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(44100)
        self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(1)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)
        self.desiredFormat.setByteOrder(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.SignedInt)
        
        self.m_buffer_1 = QByteArray()
        
        self.decoder_1 = QAudioDecoder()
        self.decoder_1.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer_1)
        self.decoder_1.finished.connect(self.decode_of_file_1_finished)
        self.decoder_1.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
        self.decoder_1.setSourceFilename(r"ΑΓΙΑ ΚΥΡΙΑΚΗ.mp3")   
        self.decoder_1.start()
        
    def decode_of_file_1_finished(self):
        self.file_1_decoded = True
        if(self.file_2_decoded):
            self.play_mp3_files()
        
    def readBuffer_1(self):
        buffer = self.decoder_1.read()
        count = buffer.byteCount()
        if(count>0):
            buffer_data = buffer.constData().asstring(count)
            self.m_buffer_1.append(buffer_data)
        else:
            return 1
            
    def decode_of_file_2_finished(self):
        self.file_2_decoded = True
        if(self.file_1_decoded):
            self.play_mp3_files()
            
    def decode_file_2(self):
        self.m_buffer_2 = QByteArray()
        
        self.decoder_2 = QAudioDecoder()
        self.decoder_2.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer_2)
        self.decoder_2.finished.connect(self.decode_of_file_2_finished)
        self.decoder_2.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
        self.decoder_2.setSourceFilename(r"ΑΓΙΟΣ ΑΝΔΡΕΑΣ.mp3")  
        self.decoder_2.start()
        
    def readBuffer_2(self):
        buffer = self.decoder_2.read()
        count = buffer.byteCount()
        if(count>0):
            buffer_data = buffer.constData().asstring(count)
            self.m_buffer_2.append(buffer_data)
        else:
            return 1
            
    def play_mp3_files(self):
        print("Two files decoded.Lets sound it.")
        self.m_play_called = False
        self.m_time_to_buffer = 50
        self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME = 100
        
        output_devices_qt = QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QtMultimedia.QAudio.AudioOutput)
        
        if (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 44100):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 10) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        elif (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 24000):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 6) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        else:
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 4) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
            
        self.m_audio_output_1 = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(output_devices_qt[0], self.desiredFormat)
        self.m_audio_output_1.setBufferSize(self.internal_buffer_size)
        
        self.m_size_to_buffer = int(self.timeToSize_1())
        
        self.m_max_size_to_buffer = self.m_size_to_buffer + int(self.timeToSize_2())
        
        self.m_output_device_1 = self.m_audio_output_1.start()
        
        self.timer_play = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
        self.timer_play.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer_play.timeout.connect(lambda:self.preplay_1(Form))
        self.timer_play.start(10)
        
        self.m_audio_output_2 = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(output_devices_qt[0], self.desiredFormat)
        self.m_audio_output_2.setBufferSize(self.internal_buffer_size)
        self.m_output_device_2 = self.m_audio_output_2.start()
        
        self.timer_play = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
        self.timer_play.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer_play.timeout.connect(lambda:self.preplay_2(Form))
        self.timer_play.start(10)
        
    def timeToSize_1(self):
        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.m_time_to_buffer / 1000)
    
    def timeToSize_2(self):
        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME / 1000)
    
            
    def preplay_1(self,Form):
        if(self.m_play_called==False):
            self.m_play_called = True
            self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
            self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
            self.timer.singleShot(0,lambda:self.sound_mp3_file_1(Form))
            
    def sound_mp3_file_1(self,Form):
        self.m_play_called = False
        if self.m_buffer_1.isEmpty():
            self.stop_playing(Form,"file_1")
            return
            
        readlen = int(self.m_audio_output_1.periodSize())
        chunks = int(self.m_audio_output_1.bytesFree() / readlen)
        
        
        while (chunks>0):
            samples_1 = self.m_buffer_1.mid(0, readlen)
            len_1 = samples_1.size()
            self.m_buffer_1.remove(0, len_1)
            
            
            if(self.m_audio_output_1.state()!=2):   
                self.m_output_device_1.write(samples_1)
            else:
                return 1

            if (len_1 != readlen):
                break

            chunks = chunks - 1
            
    def preplay_2(self,Form):
        if(self.m_play_called==False):
            self.m_play_called = True
            self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
            self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
            self.timer.singleShot(0,lambda:self.sound_mp3_file_2(Form))
            
    def sound_mp3_file_2(self,Form):
        self.m_play_called = False
        if self.m_buffer_2.isEmpty():
            self.stop_playing(Form,"file_2")
            return
            
        readlen = int(self.m_audio_output_2.periodSize())
        chunks = int(self.m_audio_output_2.bytesFree() / readlen)
        
        
        while (chunks>0):
            samples_2 = self.m_buffer_2.mid(0, readlen)
            len_2 = samples_2.size()
            self.m_buffer_2.remove(0, len_2)
            
            
            if(self.m_audio_output_2.state()!=2):   
                self.m_output_device_2.write(samples_2)
            else:
                return 1

            if (len_2 != readlen):
                break

            chunks = chunks - 1
            
    def stop_playing(self,Form,file):
        if(file=="file_1"):
            self.m_audio_output_1.stop()
        else:
            self.m_audio_output_2.stop()
        Form.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt/plugins")
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above code uses two `QAudioOutput` instances.
Works, now another question is: how can i proccess the signals (volume,speed)?